# Get MAX count but keep the repeated calculated value if highest

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, max

I have the following table, I am using SQL Server 2008

```
BayNo   FixDateTime         FixType 
1       04/05/2015 16:15:00 tyre change 
1       12/05/2015 00:15:00 oil change  
1       12/05/2015 08:15:00 engine tuning   
1       04/05/2016 08:11:00 car tuning  
2       13/05/2015 19:30:00 puncture    
2       14/05/2015 08:00:00 light repair    
2       15/05/2015 10:30:00 super op    
2       20/05/2015 12:30:00 wiper change    
2       12/05/2016 09:30:00 denting 
2       12/05/2016 10:30:00 wiper repair    
2       12/06/2016 10:30:00 exhaust repair  
4       12/05/2016 05:30:00 stereo unlock   
4       17/05/2016 15:05:00 door handle repair
```

on any given day need do find the highest number of fixes made on a given bay number, and if that calculated number is repeated then it should also appear in the resultset
so would like to see the result set as follows

```
BayNo   FixDateTime           noOfFixes 
1       12/05/2015 00:15:00   2 
2       12/05/2016 09:30:00   2 
4       12/05/2016 05:30:00   1 
4       17/05/2016 15:05:00   1
```

I manage to get the counts of each but struggling to get the max and keep the highest calculated repeated value. can someone help please

Comment: please tag your dbms.

Comment: Why do the date/time values have a time component, if the results are intended to be per day?

Comment: Yes, you are right please ignore the time component its copy and paste error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions.

Get the count for each day by bayno and also find the min fixdatetime for each day per bayno.

Then use `dense_rank` to compute the highest ranked row for each bayno based on the number of fixes.

Finally get the highest ranked rows.

```
select distinct bayno,minfixdatetime,no_of_fixes
from (
select bayno,minfixdatetime,no_of_fixes
,dense_rank() over(partition by bayno order by no_of_fixes desc) rnk
from (
select t.*, 
count(*) over(partition by bayno,cast(fixdatetime as date)) no_of_fixes,
min(fixdatetime) over(partition by bayno,cast(fixdatetime as date)) minfixdatetime
from tablename t
    ) x
) y 
where rnk = 1
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/CIDT95974)

Comment: what should we do to ignore the time component?

Comment: you mean for min fixdatetime? if so just use `min(cast(fixdatetime as date)) over(partition by bayno,cast(fixdatetime as date))`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.  I would right the query like this:

```
select bayno, thedate, numFixes
from (select bayno, cast(fixdatetime) as date) as thedate,
             count(*) as numFixes,
             rank() over (partition by cast(fixdatetime as date) order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by bayno, cast(fixdatetime as date)
     ) b
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this returns the *date* in question.  The date does not have a time component.

Comment: unfortunately, your query though looks simple but giving an error Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'.